# ha hdfs : Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I get the following error trying to start datanodes in HA HDFS cluster

> 2016-01-06 22:54:58,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory [DISK]file:/home/data/hdfs/dn/ has already been used.
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,082 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Analyzing storage directories for bpid BP-1354640905-10.146.52.232-1452117061014
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,083 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Failed to analyze storage directories for block pool BP-1354640905-10.146.52.232-1452117061014
>   java.io.IOException: BlockPoolSliceStorage.recoverTransitionRead: attempt to load an used block storage: /home/data/hdfs/dn/current/BP-1354640905-10.146.52.232-1452117061014
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceStorage.loadBpStorageDirectories(BlockPoolSliceStorage.java:210)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceStorage.recoverTransitionRead(BlockPoolSliceStorage.java:242)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.addStorageLocations(DataStorage.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:477)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1338)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1304)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:314)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:226)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:867)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,084 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Failed to add storage for block pool: BP-1354640905-10.146.52.232-1452117061014 : BlockPoolSliceStorage.recoverTransitionRead: attempt to load an used block storage: /home/data/hdfs/dn/current/BP-1354640905-10.146.52.232-1452117061014
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,084 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to master3/10.146.52.232:8020. Exiting. 
>   java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:478)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1338)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1304)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:314)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:226)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:867)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,084 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to master3/10.146.52.232:8020
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,084 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to master2/10.146.52.231:8020. Exiting. 
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Invalid volume failure  config value: 3
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.(FsDatasetImpl.java:261)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetFactory.newInstance(FsDatasetFactory.java:34)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetFactory.newInstance(FsDatasetFactory.java:30)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1351)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1304)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:314)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:226)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:867)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,085 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to master2/10.146.52.231:8020
>   2016-01-06 22:54:58,185 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned)

I have already check the clusters ID in namenode and datanode and they are similar...
I tried to reformat everything several times...
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have seen messages like this in the log file when the file system for the DataNode is corrupt. Perhaps, try running fsck -y on each of the disks used by the DataNode. In your case:

```
fsck -y /home/data/hdfs
```

Once the disk(s) is(are) clean you should be able to start the DataNode. The NameNode will work ensure that the replication factor is fixed for any lost blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (but don't know without more logs, but mine didn't say "Datanode Uuid unassigned"), and fsck didn't solve it.

In my case, I had moved a subset of disks from one node to another node that already had disks, and disabled the old node, so there was a problem with the disks not matching the DatanodeUuid of the new machine.

Above those lines in the log, there were entries like:

```
2016-04-11 19:32:02,991 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /archive14/dfs/data is in an inconsistent state: Root /archive14/dfs/data: DatanodeUuid=5ba6418e-2c24-4582-8225-3e7f7fff9feb, does not match 519c1e34-a573-41f7-9e80-dca606fce704 from other StorageDirectory.
```

To solve that, I ran:
    sed -i -r "s/${olduuid}/${olduuid}/' /mountpoints*/dfs/data/current/VERSION

This replaces the old UUID in the VERSION file with the new one. Then starting the datanode works.

Maybe in your case, you had a missing UUID rather than an incorrect one.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the name node directory and the data node directory and then creating the new directories worked for me. Use this technique assuming that you will lost the data.

Answer (score 0):

For my case,I reinstall hdfs by CM6.2.0 and instance two namenodes for HA.
Then reformat these namenode each other,but this option cause the error below.

```
Initialization failed for Block pool BP-666417012-10.253.76.213-1557044865448 (Datanode Uuid 5132035c-8d6a-4617-af7e-7d07355a905b) service to hzd-t-vbdl-02/10.253.76.222:8022 Blockpool ID mismatch: previously connected to Blockpool ID BP-666417012-10.253.76.213-1557044865448 but now connected to Blockpool ID BP-1262695848-10.253.76.222-1557045124181
```

**Process method:**

```
ansible all -m shell -a " more /XXX/hdfs/dfs/nn/current/VERSION " 
hzd-t-vbdl-01 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Sun May 05 16:27:45 CST 2019
namespaceID=732385684
clusterID=cluster54
cTime=1557044865448
storageType=NAME_NODE
blockpoolID=BP-666417012-10.253.76.213-1557044865448
layoutVersion=-64

hzd-t-vbdl-02 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Sun May 05 16:32:04 CST 2019
namespaceID=892287385
clusterID=cluster54
cTime=1557045124181
storageType=NAME_NODE
blockpoolID=BP-1262695848-10.253.76.222-1557045124181
layoutVersion=-64
```

Finally copy the context from hzd-t-vbdl-01(**early formated**) to hzd-t-vbdl-02,and restart namenodes and datanodes